# Can you identify this tree wood?

Tags: identification, trees, branches

Can somebody please help to identify this tree branch? I am located in the South of England and it was found in a small wooded area.

I include some images here:
[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]
Here is some I cut and sanded to show the actual wood.
[image: Image 3]

I'm sorry I have no leaves to show as it was just on the floor, could it be Larch?

Comment: Possibly an elm, but I'm not terribly familiar with your local tree options. Bark seems wrong for larch.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply. I think I’ve found out what it is now, a buddleia.

Answer (score 1):

No, I do not think it is a larch, which has gray bark with slightly different structure and the vertical cut should show a yellow pale colour with rings typical for conifer.

For the latter reason I will also rule out thuja and Juniperus, which are better matches for the bark colour.

Buddlejas grown in UK are shrubs not taller than 5m with multiple thin stems. Definitly not that genus.

Oak has a deeper bark structure with a greyish colour, and feels heavy/solid. You would have noticed that.

The bark of Populus/poplar comes close, but not the vertical [cut](https://www.wood-database.com/white-poplar/).

Finally, I find that [Robinia pseudoacacia (black locust)](https://www.wood-database.com/black-locust/) and [crack willow](https://www.wood-database.com/crack-willow/) matches bark and the vertical cut.

### Larch

[image: Larch]

### Oak

[image: Oak]